# Convert epoch to human readable date and time using ejs

Tags: node.js

I am using ejs for my frontend and embedded it directly into the data obtained from an `API`. The only problem is the `timestamp` is stored in `epoch`.

How do i convert epoch timestamp obtained from the `API` to human readable text in `ejs`?

Comment: Google for moment.js. It's a pretty popular library.

Comment: But that's on the server side right?

Comment: It works on both the client and server.

Comment: Will check and let you know once.

Comment: It definitely works. No need to confirm. If you have trouble with the library, open a new, more specific question.

Comment: It did work. Thanks.